# How can we start up HSQLDB server with multiple databases from Java program?

Tags: java, hsqldb, lan

In my Java application,i am starting HSQLDB server with single database successfully. It is working fine with all machines in LAN but now the problem is how to start up HSQLDB server with multiple databases from Java application ?

Comment: Please show us error logs or exceptions. This is just an information you have provided us.

Comment: @shazin,should i post my code for starting HSQLDB server with single database ? or anything else ?

Comment: Finally i achieved the functionality but how should i post my answer over stackoverflow so that it would be helpful for other people ? Thanks